# Materialized views Performance

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view

Postgres’ docs note:

> While access to the data stored in a materialized view is often much faster than accessing the underlying tables directly or through a view, the data is not always current;

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/rules-materializedviews.html

Why is it “often much faster?”

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The data of a MV is stored in a regular table, there is no magic to that. But access is typically (much) faster for multiple possible reasons:

- multiple tables joined already
- smaller row size with only relevant columns for common queries
- pre-computed values
- pre-selected rows, possibly in expensive ways
- possibly much less bloat (fewer dead tuples)
- multiple of the above items result in potentially much smaller table size as compared to underlying tables
- rows physically sorted favorably (clustered), so that queries only have to read few data pages
- size of indexes can be much smaller accordingly
- some kinds of indexes only become possibly this way, like a multicolumn index on columns from multiple underlying tables

In short: most expensive work of sophisticated queries on underlying tables is already done, which allows potentially much faster access.

Comment: but when you refresh a materialized view, wont it just drop everything and recalculate? lets say you are storing likes and dislikes counts in a mat view. a person likes a post so you just need to add 1 more like to a single post id but the mat view ll recompute votes for every post correct?

Comment: @PirateApp: The MV never refreshes by itself. Only when you tell it to do so, with [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html). But yes, the whole table is re-computed. Notably, if very few rows actually change, using `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY` is typically faster, as it computes the new table in the background and then updates rows that actually changed.

Answer (score 3):

Materialized Views help you pre-calculate data. If you don't use that tool correctly, it may be slower to use them.

Here is an example:

```
test=> create table my_table
  (id integer generated always as identity,
   time timestamptz);
CREATE TABLE                                           ^
test=> alter table my_table add constraint pk_my_table primary key (id);
ALTER TABLE
test=> insert into my_table (time)
test->  (select time_series
test(>   from generate_series('2019-02-25','2019-03-25', '1 minutes'::interval) as time_series);
INSERT 0 40321
                                                             ^
test=> explain analyze select * from my_table where time between now() and now() + '1 minute'::interval;
                                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on my_table  (cost=0.00..1125.22 rows=2 width=12) (actual time=0.093..4.642 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (("time" >= now()) AND ("time" <= (now() + '00:01:00'::interval)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 40320
 Planning Time: 0.132 ms
 Execution Time: 4.657 ms
(5 rows)

test=> create materialized view my_materialized_view as
test-> (select * from my_table);
SELECT 40321
test=> explain analyze select * from my_materialized_view where time between now() and now() + '1 minute'::interval;
                                                     QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on my_materialized_view  (cost=0.00..1218.62 rows=222 width=12) (actual time=0.859..28.983 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (("time" >= now()) AND ("time" <= (now() + '00:01:00'::interval)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 40320
 Planning Time: 0.352 ms
 Execution Time: 29.053 ms
(5 rows)
```

If your materialized view is poorly designed (or not design for that particular query) or if you don't have enough data, you may have slower query by using a materialized view.